# How can I use values from an index-defining array as the index to define a value in an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I'm attempting a complex transformation to an image, where, for simplicities sake, a new image is created where every pixel at location (x, y) is defined as the location (X(x), Y(x)) in the original image, where X() and Y() are the functions that determine what pixel the transformed result is coming from on the original image. Currently, I am just iterating through every value for x and y and assigning the pixel colors this way, but it is too slow and I have been trying to use array indexing but it doesn't work.

This is my current working solution, but I can't figure out another way to do it without iteration:

I first create a basic index array (I don't know if there's an actual name for it) where each value at location (x, y) is equal to (x, y)

```
index arr:
[ [[0 0][0 1][0 2]]
  [[1 0][1 1][1 2]]
  [[2 0][2 1][2 2]] ]
```

(this would be an example if it were just a 3x3 array, I am dealing with whole images)

I then create a new index array for the transformation. Say that my transformation was to move every pixel clockwise around the center, the new transformation defining array would be:

```
transformed index array:
[ [[1 0][0 0][0 1]]
  [[2 0][1 1][0 2]]
  [[2 1][2 2][1 2]] ]
```

so then the new, transformed image would be one where the pixel at [0, 0] would be the pixel in the original image at [1, 0], and [0, 1] would be the original at [0, 0], so on and so forth according to the transformed index array, such as the following

```
[ [1  2  3]           [ [4  1  2]
  [4  5  6]     ~~~>    [7  5  3]
  [7  8  9] ]           [8  9  6] ]
```

My issue is I can't see a way of defining the transformed array in this way without iterating through each pixel and assigning the value from the original image that it should be. I tried using slicing to do this:

```
original_im = cv2.imread('im.jpg')
transposed_im = original_im.copy()     #copy original image then to get same shape and data type
transposed_im[:, :, :] = 0             #set all pixels to (0, 0, 0) before assigning them
transformed_index_arr = np.array([ [[1 0][0 0][0 1]]
                                   [[2 0][1 1][0 2]]
                                   [[2 1][2 2][1 2]] ])
transposed_im[:, :] = original_im[ transformed_index_arr[:, :]]
```

I know this doesn't work, but the way I normally understand the ":" operator is as "for each index in the dimension", so whenever I attempt to run this code it tries to use the whole transformed_index_arr list as the slice for original_im, even though all I want is the respective slice to point to the pixel's location in the original image.

Long story short, how can I solve this problem without iteration? I'm not an expert enough in np and array indexing to figure this one out so any help is greatly appreciated. I just haven't been able to find a resource that can explain how to do a non-linear transformation such as this, or explain how I can use this index-defining array (is that what it can be called?) to define the transposed image.

Comment: Well, I found a solution. cv2.remap was exactly the functionality I was looking for. I simply made a map for the x and y values and then applied the cv2.map to obtain the transformed image

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
import numpy as np
    
transformed_index_arr = np.array(
    [[[1, 0], [0, 0], [0, 1]], [[2, 0], [1, 1], [0, 2]], [[2, 1], [2, 2], [1, 2]]]
)

original_im = np.arange(9).reshape([3, 3]) + 1
transposed_im = original_im[
    (transformed_index_arr[..., 0], transformed_index_arr[..., 1])
]
```

This yields

```
>>> original_im 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])

>>> transposed_im
array([[4, 1, 2],
       [7, 5, 3],
       [8, 9, 6]])
```

Comment: what is the '...' in (transformed_index_arr[..., 0], transformed_index_arr[..., 1])?

Comment: It's a shortcut to `:` in all trailing axes. In this case, it's the same as `transformed_index_arr[:, :, 0]`